Building google test as a DLL in Visual Studio 2022 linking errors
I just cloned https://github.com/google/googletest, created a new visual studio (2022 professional) DLL project and copied directories https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest/include/ and https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest/src into the project folder and added $(ProjectDir);$(ProjectDir)include to the project's "Properties --> C++ --> Additional Include Directories" and then replaced all #include "gtest/ with #include "../include/gtest/ and all #include "src/ with #include "../src/ and built the project. Compilation went fine but linking did not as I had roughly 400 linking errors :
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl testing::AssertionResult::AssertionResult(class testing::AssertionResult const &)" (??0AssertionResult@testing@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionResult::operator!(void)const " (??7AssertionResult@testing@@QEBA?AV01@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionFailure(class testing::Message const &)" (?AssertionFailure@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@AEBVMessage@1@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionFailure(void)" (?AssertionFailure@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionSuccess(void)" (?AssertionSuccess@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-assertion-result.obj : error LNK2005: "private: void __cdecl testing::AssertionResult::swap(class testing::AssertionResult &)" (?swap@AssertionResult@testing@@AEAAXAEAV12@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl testing::internal::DeathTest::DeathTest(void)" (??0DeathTest@internal@testing@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl testing::ExitedWithCode::ExitedWithCode(int)" (??0ExitedWithCode@testing@@QEAA@H@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __cdecl testing::ExitedWithCode::operator()(int)const " (??RExitedWithCode@testing@@QEBA_NH@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual void __cdecl testing::internal::DeathTestImpl::Abort(enum testing::internal::DeathTest::AbortReason)" (?Abort@DeathTestImpl@internal@testing@@MEAAXW4AbortReason@DeathTest@23@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual enum testing::internal::DeathTest::TestRole __cdecl testing::internal::WindowsDeathTest::AssumeRole(void)" (?AssumeRole@WindowsDeathTest@internal@testing@@UEAA?AW4TestRole@DeathTest@23@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool __cdecl testing::internal::DeathTest::Create(char const *,class testing::Matcher<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &>,char const *,int,class testing::internal::DeathTest * *)" (?Create@DeathTest@internal@testing@@SA_NPEBDV?$Matcher@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@3@0HPEAPEAV123@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual bool __cdecl testing::internal::DefaultDeathTestFactory::Create(char const *,class testing::Matcher<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &>,char const *,int,class testing::internal::DeathTest * *)" (?Create@DefaultDeathTestFactory@internal@testing@@UEAA_NPEBDV?$Matcher@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@3@0HPEAPEAVDeathTest@23@@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl testing::internal::ExitedUnsuccessfully(int)" (?ExitedUnsuccessfully@internal@testing@@YA_NH@Z) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl testing::internal::DeathTestImpl::GetErrorLogs(void)" (?GetErrorLogs@DeathTestImpl@internal@testing@@MEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl testing::internal::GetLastErrnoDescription(void)" (?GetLastErrnoDescription@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest-death-test.obj : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl testing::internal::InDeathTestChild(void)" (?InDeathTestChild@internal@testing@@YA_NXZ) already defined in gtest-all.obj
...
1>gtest.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > testing::FLAGS_gtest_stream_result_to" (?FLAGS_gtest_stream_result_to@testing@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > testing::FLAGS_gtest_flagfile" (?FLAGS_gtest_flagfile@testing@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>gtest.obj : error LNK2005: "void const * const testing::internal::kTestTypeIdInGoogleTest" (?kTestTypeIdInGoogleTest@internal@testing@@3QEBXEB) already defined in gtest-all.obj
1>C:\Googletest\x64\Debug\Googletest.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

What am I doing wrong ?

Why are you not using CMake to build the project with the -DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 flag?

only god can know what is the wrong thing you have xddd

@HamzaAlAjlouni - that is not a helpful comment. If your going to participate on SO, be polite.

@selbie okay -_-

it looks like that you have duplication in somewhere, maybe you have linked something twice or compiled it twice.

gtest-all.cpp is an SCU-style translation unit, combining stuff from other translation units. You should either build only this one unit or only other the rest of translation units excluding this one.

@selbie This cherished old times are definitively gone ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzSzwQOmMRs Well I tried cmale but I never ever used it, I understand I should create a CMakeList.txt etc, but don't even find one in the googletest folder I just cloned.

Problem is #include "src/. why you have it at all?

@11house this YT is made by some beginner. This is poor source of knowledge.

@marek : yes, I spotted independently that the sources are not needed by remarking that they are not even present in the package files would you install gtest from nuget.

That video you shared is 13 years old. Did you consider that maybe it's out of date?

"and then replaced all #include (...)" - do not replace anything. Leave googletest sources as they are, and use googletest in your code like this: #include <gtest/gtest.h>. If that doesn't work, you misconfigured your project.

I don't use MSVC, but this answer seems to explain very well what needs to be done.

Be aware, that Microsoft now supports gtest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022 so follow this instruction.

@MarekR Beware, doing so involves adding a google test nuget package to the project and the source code of this nuget is minimum 5 years old ...

@selbie I'm not saying this youtube tutorial is relevant now, I am saying that it was at that time, and that at that time using gtest in visual studio was made obvious by google, which is not the case now.

@MarekR If you remove all sources you have unresolved external link error, I incrementally found the minimal set of source files needed to make the link without errors. Nevertheless thanks to you as it narrowed down the good thing to do.

gtest sources should not be part of your target. Those suppose to be accessible after you properly link gtest library., Like I wrote follow MS instructions.

@MarekR No, but I could compile (which I intend to) them into a DLL and link to that DLL in a test project.

a google test nuget package to the project and the source code of this nuget is minimum 5 years old Use vcpkg, it has a two weeks old version.
